# Fill in the missing entries of $Q$ to make $Q$ an orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, orthogonality

I need to fill in the missing entries of $Q$ to make $Q$ an orthogonal matrix. I have no idea how to solve this problem out. I was hoping for some hints on how to go about this.

> Problem: $$Q=
>         \begin{bmatrix}
>         1/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt3 & * \\
>         0 & 1/\sqrt3 & * \\
>         -1/\sqrt2 & 1/\sqrt3 & * \\
>         \end{bmatrix}
> $$

I know that, just by looking at the problem that $$V_1=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        -1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
and $$V_2=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: What are $\;v_1,v_2\;$  supposed to show/prove/relate to ?

Comment: Aren't they the orthogonal basis for W and then I have q1 and q2 which are the orthonormal basis. I need to find q3.

Comment: Please terminate the last sentence of the question; leaving it like this, we will never know what you intended to do with those columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a third vector that is orthogonal to both $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$, we take their cross product:
$$
\vec v_1 \times \vec v_2 = \begin{vmatrix}
\vec i & \vec j & \vec k \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}
= \vec i - 2\vec j + \vec k
= \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ -2 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Normalizing, we obtain:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\tfrac{1}{\sqrt 6} \\ \tfrac{-2}{\sqrt 6} \\ \tfrac{1}{\sqrt 6}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Wow that was easier than I thought. Thank you!